# XeLaTeX warning: Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm'

Tags: xetex, fontspec, warnings

I updated my MiKTeX to the newest version a few days ago, and after this when I compile documents with the `fontspec` package included, there's a warning. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\begin{document}
  Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Build Output shows:

```
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 107.
*************************************************
```

Why this happens? How to solve it?

Comment: It's simply an innocuous warning.

Comment: @egreg: Should it really be a warning then? It can well confuse users.

Comment: @Andrey: `xparse` raise a warning whenever one use `\RenewDocumentCommand`, since redefining a macro is always at some risk. There are also some other innocuous warnings, e.g. some of the font substitution warnings.

Comment: @LeoLiu: I understand that redefining macros has potential harm. But I believe that issuing a warning means requiring the user to take an _action_ to fix this warning. Here we can take no action and no action is even required; we can't get rid of the warning (which means that now I can't tailor my document to _not generate_ any warnings). Hence I think this should be an `info`, not a warning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be possible to silence this kind of messages via

```
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
```

but the option to `xparse` is currently broken and has no effect. The version I'm referring is

```
xparse.sty 3471 2012-02-26
```

All these packages are quite new and developing, so warning messages can help debug problems. However, the message you're referring to is completely harmless.

Comment: The issue isn't in `xparse` _per se_ but is to do with how (or indeed if) kernel-level messages are filtered out. There will be some update on this over the next week or so.

Comment: This is still happening - I am very new to Latex, like 1 day, and I agree with comments above - Why warn about something the user has no way of fixing!?
Now do I read every warning and try to work out what is important and what is not!?
Or do I just ignore ALL Warnings and not try to understand what is going on with them .... Confused newbie!

Comment: @user35378 -- xparse is easier to program than the corresponding latex 2e stuff, but it remains experimental.  if you're a 1-day-old latex programmer, you were badly advised: far better to use "standard" stuff than to use stuff that is still in development, in your situation.  ... imho.

Comment: @wasteofspace I believe that user35378 is complaining that `fontspec` is still issuing the warning. The solution, of course, is to update the TeX distribution.